# Spring Actuator, not able to expose even after trying somany options

Tags: spring-boot-actuator

I'm trying to explore the Spring actuator endpoints through springboot project. I'm unable to expose any of the endpoints. It always shows the 'Exposing 1 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator' in log. Below is my dependency details added in build.gradle and application.yml file. I have used spring security as well, to expose the endpoint only to user with certain role. But still nothing works. Requesting suggestions.

build.gradle:

implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'

implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'

implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'

I'm using Spring boot version 2.6.6

application.yml

management:
endpoint:
health:
show-details: always
endpoints:
web:
exposure:
include: health

Spring Security :

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity

public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/actuator/**").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN")
            .anyRequest().permitAll()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .permitAll();
    http.csrf().disable().headers().frameOptions().disable();
}
```

}

Comment: try removing the role - hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN") and see if its working

Comment: Tried this. But it still exposes only basic /health endpoint.

Comment: Is there any other suggestions, what ever the changes I make to application.yml the endpoints are not getting exposed. Not sure, what I'm missing in configuration

Answer (score 1):

The issue was with the `application.yml`. The `management.endpoint.web.exposure.health` was added below the Spring entry. The actuator entry needed to be added *above* that.